# Converting string to datetime [hh:mm:ss]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two columns Date_x and Date_y. I would like to compare them (i.e Date_x + 1 hour < Date_y)

Format of the strings looks as follows "2020-01-29 11:31:32.754292 UTC"

I have tried converting it using datetime:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
df["Date_x"] = [dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for x in df['Date_x']]
```

However, it throws an error regarding the UTC part. I tried removing it with no avail.

Last traceback:

```
time data '2020-01-29 18:30:28' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How would you go about converting the string to hh:mm:ss only?

Comment: In principle, you'll want to use `pd.to_datetime` if working with datetime in pandas. However, the question is kind of unclear to me - you mention an example "2020-01-29 11:31:32.754292 UTC", however in your error you have '2020-01-29 18:30:28'. Your parsing directive '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' doesn't match either of these. Could you please clarify? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: @MrFuppes I managed to solve it. Thanks for the pd.to_datetime suggestion. There was apparently multiple dates with different formats so while it may have gotten one of them, it did not get the other. I simple did pd.to_datetime(df["Date_x"]) and it solved it after some time.

Comment: ok so if you have mixed formats in the input strings, some specifying UTC (or UTC offset), some not, then: IF you know all date/times refer to UTC, remove UTC from the string first, then [localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) to UTC again *after* conversion to datetime data type. Or just leave that datetime naive (tz not set); pandas treats naive datetime as UTC (in contrast to native Python).

Comment: for an output back to string, I'd suggest [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it's an ISO standard and pretty common, meaning for example that there are tools for parsing readily available in most programming languages. Formatting directive would be `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `if` statement:

```
df["Date_x"] = [dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') if '.' in x else dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in df['Date_x']]
```

But why not just `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df["Date_x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_x"], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried pd.to_datetime, but it seems to take a long time and has not yet completed.

Comment: @OscarDyremyhr Use the first solution I gave... Anyway, both solutions should work :) Please accept and upvote if it helps :)

Comment: if working with pandas, pd.to_datetime should be the way to go (maybe with keyword `infer_datetime_format=True`). Also note that neither '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' nor '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' matches "2020-01-29 11:31:32.754292 UTC"

Comment: @MrFuppes Ah yes! added it, thanks for the tip

Comment: @U12-Forward kind of hard to say if it will actually help since it depends on the input the OP has - that's the "*maybe*" ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes Yeap! `pd.to_datetime` should be the way to go!

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks fot the help. Problem solved with given solution. There was mixed date formats in the datasets so it was a bit tricky to specify the format. I just left it out (infer format seems to work too). In regards to the if statement, it does work once i remove the UTC part of the string. If i were to be given a similar date would you know what format the UTC part should be written as?   I assume something like '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f  ????'

Comment: Love the `infer_datetime_format`, I didn't know about this!